# How can i prove PCA is a better model than FA?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis

I am running some factor and PCA analyses, and it is clear that PCA (atleast visually) for my kind of data is working alot better. How can i provide evidence that PCA is the right model, outside of seeing that the variables grouped for each component are near perfect, compared to the factor analysis which is not.

Comment: I don't think you can - PCA and FA are different techniques with different goals. Which one you do should not be based on the data.

Comment: Consider the article Okamoto, M. (1969). Optimality of principal components. In P. R. Krishnaiah (Ed.) Multivariate analysis II (pp. 673–685). North-Holland.  Therein, you will find that PC has certain optimality properties; so in terms of those properties, PC is definitely better than FA or anything else. On the other hand, if you start with the Gaussian FA model and estimate its parameters (in a way that ensures identifiability) by using maximum likelihood, then those estimates will be better than estimates based on PCs or anything else. As the previous answer indicates, it all depends.

Comment: Could you define "Better" model? How you know A model is better that others. What is the measure you used?